# Is there a way to use absolute paths in React with ALL IDEs?

Tags: reactjs, ide, relative-path

I was super excited to read this article: https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d

It outlines a way to introduce a `.env` file in the root of the front-end code to allow "absolute" paths like `utils/requests` rather than paths like `../../../utils/requests`.  So I implemented it and ... it worked.  For me, that is.

But when my colleague loaded his code into PyCharm (and I assume WebStorm) then it failed because those IDEs don't support this approach.

Given that it's almost 2020, I'm wondering if there's a way to allow absolute paths in React that work in EVERY IDE?

Comment: Most of the time, it's a webpack or babel configuration, so it's unrelated to the IDE. If their IDE fails with these aliases, they should look into configuring the IDE to take the babel or webpack configuration into account, but that's on a case by case basis.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank you.  Do you know of any good articles or discussions on how to configure webpack or babel to allow this?

Comment: The very article you link to is using webpack's DefinePlugin in the background, so your configuration is probably already fine. It's your colleague that either need to use the same tools as the rest of the team, or find ways to make it work with their IDE of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `package.json` you can do

```
  "dependencies": {
    "my-math": "file:local_modules/my-math",
    "my-util": "file:local_modules/my-util"
  }
```

and can use in your file

```
import { add } from 'my-math';
import { something } from 'my-util';
```

You can also in webpack do

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@util': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util')
    }
  }
```

and can use in your file

```
import { something } from '@util';
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this not what is being asked? Or a close enough answer?